# How to block Xwindow screen area from cursor?

Tags: xorg, multi-monitor, xrandr, x-server, cursor

I have two monitors configured to have one screen area. I need to forbid any cursor movement for one monitor, while let it freely move across another monitor. How can I do this? I tried using panning in different ways in xrandr, but no result.